# Passing a header through chained services

Tags: javascript, node.js, service

I'm calling two services using npm-request and npm-async, combining their results, and showing them to a user. (Service 1: hello; Service 2: world; Service 3: Hello world). I'd like to pass an ID through the headers to trace the route of the calls.

```
  helloString = 'Nothing';
  worldString = 'Yet';

  async.series([
  function(callback){
      // call helloService
      request('http://localhost:3000/hello', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
          callback(null, body);
        }
        else {
          callback(err, null);
        }
      })
  },
  function(callback){
      // call worldService
      request('http://localhost:3001/world', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
          callback(null, body);
        }
        else {
          callback(err, null);
        }
      })
  }
  ],
  // optional callback
  function(err, results){
      // results is now equal to ['hello', 'world']
      console.log('*************');
      console.log(results[0] + ' ' + results[1]);
      console.log('*************');
      res.send(results[0] + ' ' + results[1]);
  });
```

What I'd like to do is intercept both of these calls and add a custom header, almost like I wrote this:

```
request({url: 'http://localhost:3000/hello', headers: {'id': '12345'}}, function (error, response, body) {...
```

But without having to manually type it each time.

So far, I've tried putting this inside each of the services' server.js files:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if (req.headers["id"]) {
      console.log('service was given id: ' + req.headers["id"]);
      res.writeHead(200, {"id": req.headers["id"]});
      console.log('set res header id to ' + res._headers["id"]);
    }
    else {
      console.log("I wasn't passed the ID");
    }
    next();
});
```

I seem to be correctly grabbing the ID, but have trouble passing it to the next service. This is the error that I am getting:

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following jfriend00's advice, I built a wrapper around the request() module to do exactly what I wanted! It was a great learning experience, and if you'd like to read how I did it, I wrote it up [here](http://www.samjhill.com/blog/?p=514).

Answer (score 2):

In you server.js service files, change this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {"id": req.headers["id"]});
```

to this:

```
res.setHeader("id", req.headers["id"]);
```

`res.writeHead()` is trying to write out all headers and finish the header part of the response.  That is not yet what you want to do in middleware.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you. That took care of the error, but unfortunately, the headers still aren't being received by the secondary services. These were the headers passed to the helloService (I got this with req.headers) : { host: 'localhost:3000', connection: 'close' }

Comment: @SamuelHill - here's a demo of how you send custom headers with `request()`: https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers

Comment: @jfrend00 Thank you! I understand, but what I need to do is intercept that request and add the headers, not add the headers manually for each call.

Comment: @SamuelHill - What do you mean "intercept that request"?  There is no such thing as middleware for outgoing requests.  You could make your own `requestWithId()` function that would add the header to every request sent through it and then use that function everywhere.  Not sure what else you're expecting here.

Comment: I see - thank you! I'm hoping to be able to attach the header to every outgoing request without having to use another function or add any code to each request.

Comment: @SamuelHill - you'd have to mess with the `request()` module itself (or some lower level module that it uses) to do that.  There is no general purpose hook for modifying outgoing requests.  Also, unless the `id` value was stuck in a global variable, I don't see how you'd know what id to set it to either since that would usually come from the calling code context.